# How can we update or create new MSK trigger for a lambda function via api

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I am trying to update the existing MSK trigger my lambda function by adding topics to the list via API. If Editing is not possible I am also open to creating a new MSK trigger.

This new trigger will be added to the existing lambda via another lambda function that would have its own events.

Can someone guide me:

1. Is it even possible to edit the existing MSK trigger via APIs.
2. Or, can new MSK triggers be added and attached via API?

Tried digging the documentations:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_event_invoke_config
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#putFunctionEventInvokeConfig-property

Code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('./config')
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: config.AWS_REGION});

const listEventSource = async () => {
    var params = {
        FunctionName: config.LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
    };
    res = await lambda.listEventSourceMappings(params).promise()
    console.log(res)
};

const createMSKTrigger = async ()=>{
    var params = {
        FunctionName: config.LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME,
        BatchSize: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        BisectBatchOnFunctionError: true || false,
        DestinationConfig: {
            OnFailure: {
                Destination: 'STRING_VALUE'
            },
            OnSuccess: {
                Destination: 'STRING_VALUE'
            }
        },
        Enabled: true || false,
        EventSourceArn: 'STRING_VALUE',
        FunctionResponseTypes: [
            ReportBatchItemFailures,
            /* more items */
        ],
        MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        ParallelizationFactor: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        Queues: [
            'STRING_VALUE',
            /* more items */
        ],
        SelfManagedEventSource: {
            Endpoints: {
                '<EndPointType>': [
                    'STRING_VALUE',
                    /* more items */
                ],
                /* '<EndPointType>': ... */
            }
        },
        SourceAccessConfigurations: [
            {
                Type: BASIC_AUTH | VPC_SUBNET | VPC_SECURITY_GROUP | SASL_SCRAM_512_AUTH | SASL_SCRAM_256_AUTH,
                URI: 'STRING_VALUE'
            },
            /* more items */
        ],
        StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON | LATEST | AT_TIMESTAMP,
        StartingPositionTimestamp: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
        Topics: [
            'STRING_VALUE',
            /* more items */
        ],
        TumblingWindowInSeconds: 'NUMBER_VALUE'
    };
    triggerRes = lambda.createEventSourceMapping(params).promise()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python - Boto3**

You can update the trigger using [update_event_source mapping](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_event_source_mapping) method.

You can create the trigger using [create_event_source mapping](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping) method.

**Javascript - AWS SDK**

You can update the trigger using [UpdateEventSourceMappingCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/updateeventsourcemappingcommand.html) class.

You can create the trigger using [CreateEventSourceMappingCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/createeventsourcemappingcommand.html) class.

Below are the AWS documentation "Using Lambda with Amazon MSK".
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-msk.html

I hope this can help you with your issue.